# Read Data from unknown Bluetooth Device while communicating

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to figure out how the FORA d15b blood pressure monitoring system communicates via Bluetooth.  I want to be able to eventually write an Android app that can receive blood pressure data from the device.

More specifically, I want to know the exact data to send to the device in order to request blood pressure information.  I also want to know the data that the device sends out.  However, I don't even know the format of the data being sent/received.

I know that FORA has a PC app that can communicate with the d15b device via Bluetooth but I don't know what information its sending/receiving over Bluetooth, and that's what I want to know.

Here is Bluetooth information I know about the d15b device:
Bluetooth Carrier Frequency: 2400MHz to 2483.5MHz
Bluetooth Modulation Method: GFSK, 1Mbps, 0.5BT Gaussian
Transmission Power: +3dBm to –20dBm; Power control 4 stage 
Receiving Signal Range: -88dBm to -20 dBm
Receiver IF Frequency: 1.5MHz center frequency
Maximum Data Rate: Asynchronous:723.2kbps/57.6kbps;
                   Synchronous: 433.9kbps/433.9kbps

I'm struggling to even find a starting point.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

I am familiar with C, Java, and Arduino if that helps at all...

NOTE:
Unfortunately, I am new to Bluetooth.  After doing some research, I am still pretty clueless on how to solve this problem.  In the title, I say unknown Bluetooth device because I just want to be able to read what I/O of an unknown Bluetooth device, which in my case happens to be the d15b that I know nothing about.  Sorry if the question has been addressed already or if this is an inappropriate place to post this question.  I wasn't sure.

Answer (score -1):

Bluetooth data is encrypted. So it's not possible to hack it easily. 
Forget it.